# Query Mongodb with empty and non-empty values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

MongoDB Object Structure

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("59db626f6944c019616eb9cf"),
    "category" : "Flat",
    "purpose" : "SALE",
    "price" : 2000,
    "area" : 2,
    "lotArea" : 2,
    "description" : "nothing",
    "features" : {
        "beds" : 3,
        "baths" : 3,
        "totalRooms" : 2,
        "dining" : true,
        "furnishing" : true,
        "flooring" : true,
        "servantQuarter" : true,
        "waterHeating" : true,
        "ceiling" : true,
        "cooling" : "Central",
        "heating" : "Central",
        "installedAppliances" : [
            "nothing"
        ]
    },
    "dealerId" : [ ],
    "images" : [ ],
    "loc" : {
        "latitude" : "33.652324769150894",
        "longitude" : "72.95517927486878"
    },
    "address" : {
        "city" : "Islamabad",
        "house_no" : "1",
        "street_no" : "1",
        "sector" : "G-13",
        "area_description" : "commercial"
    },
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59db62a06944c019616eb9d0"),
    "category" : "Flat",
    "purpose" : "SALE",
    "price" : 2001,
    "area" : 1,
    "lotArea" : 1,
    "description" : "nothing",
    "features" : {
        "beds" : 2,
        "baths" : 2,
        "totalRooms" : 2,
        "flooring" : true,
        "furnishing" : true,
        "ceiling" : true,
        "waterHeating" : true,
        "servantQuarter" : true,
        "dining" : true,
        "cooling" : "AC",
        "heating" : "Central",
        "installedAppliances" : [
            "nothing"
        ]
    },
    "dealerId" : [ ],
    "images" : [ ],
    "loc" : {
        "latitude" : "33.65243977011859",
        "longitude" : "72.9547689790985"
    },
    "address" : {
        "city" : "Islamabad",
        "house_no" : "11",
        "street_no" : "1",
        "sector" : "G-13",
        "area_description" : "dd"
    },
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59db7ae1bfbdd82adf9c5ddc"),
    "category" : "Flat",
    "purpose" : "SALE",
    "price" : 20000,
    "area" : 2,
    "lotArea" : 2,
    "description" : "nothing",
    "features" : {
        "beds" : 2,
        "baths" : 2,
        "totalRooms" : 1,
        "ceiling" : true,
        "furnishing" : true,
        "flooring" : true,
        "waterHeating" : true,
        "dining" : true,
        "servantQuarter" : true,
        "cooling" : "AC",
        "heating" : "Heaters",
        "installedAppliances" : [
            "nothing"
        ]
    },
    "dealerId" : [ ],
    "images" : [ ],
    "loc" : {
        "latitude" : "33.664966530995855",
        "longitude" : "72.99625174581297"
    },
    "address" : {
        "city" : "Islamabad",
        "house_no" : "1",
        "street_no" : "1",
        "sector" : "G-11",
        "area_description" : "commercial"
    },
    "__v" : 0
```

I want to query some data based on an empty and non-empty string for example

```
db.properties.find({"purpose":"SALE,"address.city":""}).pretty()
```

if user enters "purpose" value but doesn't enter the "address.city" value then only those data should return that is of the purpose of sale and if there is a value for "address.city" entered by user e.g.

```
db.properties.find({"purpose":"SALE,"address.city":"Islamabad"}).pretty()
```

Now the data must be of purpose sale of that particular city.

Actually, I need that type of query for advanced search which handle the value if empty or not empty in  $and logical condition and I have a long list of possibilities that to should query data from MongoDB on the user advance search selection.

Comment: This looks very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315649

Answer (score 0):

You may need a list of cities to find after $in that includes the null value like this:

```
db.properties.find({"purpose":"SALE,"address.city":{$in : [null, "City1", "City2"]}});
```

This will return resutls for both the cities you want and empty value.

Comment: Let suppose we are using a variable to get value, but what if the user doesn't enter a value at all. After all it's for advance search purpose, he may or may not enter the value but if he enter the value then we must query for the data of purpose sell of the user enter city name.                                                          db.properties.find({"purpose":"SALE,"address.city":req.body.city).pretty()